# Unable to send data from actionResult to asyn mothod in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jsonresult

This is my controller actionReslt

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken()] 
    public ActionResult PaymentDetails(PaymentViewModel payment)
    {
        PaymentModel paymentModel = new PaymentModel();
        //  AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<PaymentModel, PaymentViewModel>();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {               

            CreditCardDetailsModel creditCardDetailsModel = new CreditCardDetailsModel();
            creditCardDetailsModel.SecurityId = payment.SecurityId;
            creditCardDetailsModel.ExpiryDate = payment.Month + payment.Year;
            creditCardDetailsModel.CardNumber = payment.CardNumber;
            paymentModel.CreditCardDetails = creditCardDetailsModel;
            return RedirectToAction("Payment",paymentModel);
        } 
        return View("FlightBooking");
    }
```

and this is my async method

```
  public async Task<JsonResult> Payment(PaymentModel model)
    {
        CreateFormOfPaymentReplyModel response = new CreateFormOfPaymentReplyModel();
        resource = Constants.Payment;
        response = await Post<CreateFormOfPaymentReplyModel>(model);

        resource = Constants.PnrConfirm;
        var pnrConformStatus = await Get<PNRConfirmResponseModel>();
        return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = false, message = response } };

    }
```

and i want to return to Payment method with paymentObject if it is valid but PaymentModel is returning null data and it is showing the error as

```
This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet
```

Comment: JsonResult { Data = new { status = false, message = response }, JsonBehaviour.AllowGet };

Try this

Comment: i didn't get you, i want to redirect to payment method along with data(paymentmodel) but i am getting empty data after coming to Payment  Method

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing allowget to your return variable?

i.e:

```
 return Json( new { status = false, message = response }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Hope this helps.